# Usage of writable store within 2 components

Tags: svelte

I have two components A and B. Whenever I update data in any of the component it gets stored in a writable store. But when I try to set value to another store using a click function I am not able  to set it.

I debugged it and found `afterUpdate()` in component B is causing this issue. But I need it because I am using the values from component A and doing some filteration in component B and save them in store.

When I change it to `onMount()` the click function works but the component B is not getting the changes made in component A.

Below is the just an idea on how my code looks. Sorry could not paste the complete code here as it is huge.

```js
const store = writable(null);
const storePages = writable(null);

componentA.subscribe((state)=> {
    //do some logic and store the results in a store
    store.set(resultsA)
});

afterUpdate(() => {
   componentB.subscribe((state) => {
   //use the store value from component A and do some filteration and save it back to the store
   store.set(resultsB)
})
            
store.subscribe((value)=> { });
storePages.subscribe((value)=> { });   
 
function page({detail}) {
    storePages.set(someValue based on store)
}
```

Comment: That looks wrong on multiple levels. In general you should not need to use `subscribe` in components and if used, subscriptions should be cleaned up later. You certainly should not add subscription in an `afterUpdate` which would add more and more subscriptions over time. In general you should not need `afterUpdate` at all; I have written  a lot of Svelte code and never needed it. If your code is not reactive without it, you are almost certainly doing something wrong. If anything, use reactive statements (`$: ...`) and for stores use auto-subscriptions (`$store`) within component code.

Comment: without afterUpdate() is there a way to listen to changes of component A inside component B. Though I have used the same store without afterUpdate() I am not able to listen to those changes

Comment: If you need to propagate changes up from a component, you would usually just use `bind:property` (to bind to variable or a store) and a reactive statement using said property.

Comment: Or of course use events, if that is more appropriate.